# Working c# application from another PC with SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, desktop-application

I have a C# application with SQL Server, and I have one database and lots of tables. If I want run this application from another PC, what can I do?

For example I will set up SQL Server 2012 Express on the other PC, then should I attach my database? Or anyway? Second question when I install just SQL Server 2012 Express, how can I attach my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server and C# are made to talk to each other across machines (client/server). To connect from a C# program to a SQL Server database you need to know the instance name (the SQL Server install where you can have more then one instance per physical machine), the database name and depending on whether you are using built in security (where you are using your sign in account on the client which has privileges on the server) or not in which case you need to provide a user name/password that does have privileges on the server.